# Forward incoming mail with appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, gmail

i'm very newbie at this apps scripts...

I'm trying to figure out how to forward an incoming e-mail that matches this 2 conditions:

- from: email@example.com
- Subject: Some Text here

if it's true, then forward to:

- 6 different e-mails (i have them under a label in my contacts)

I have not really tried a script for this, i just searched a lot and there are many scripts but with much more variables and conditions than my needs
i think what i expect is simple, but can't certainly know for sure

Comment: Hi. Regrettably StackOverflow isn't a bespoke scripting service; we can help you solve a problem but prefer not to do your work for you. Why not show us what you've done and we'll see how we can help with that.

Comment: Look here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message

Comment: Thanks! i'll see what i can get from there!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to forward all incoming Gmail to a group of 6 people who are listed under a label in your Contacts.

This answer consists of two functions:

- `fwdEmail`:

  - queries GMail for new email
  - gets "to" addresses from a given `Contacts` group/label
  - forwards the email
  - "marks" the email `as read`
- `contactsEmail`:

  - gets email addresses of ALL members of the label/Group
  - passes the email addresses to `fwdEmail`.

---

**ISSUES**

**Trigger**

- There are no built-in triggers for GMail. So the project is structured as follows:

  - create a new spreadsheet and use the Project Editor for that spreadsheet.
  - create a `time-driven trigger` for `fwdNewEmail`

    - the frequency will depend on your circumstances.

**Contacts - Email addresses**

- The "Contacts service" for apps script has been deprecated.
- Information about `Contacts` is now accessed via the [Advanced People Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people)`.
- The [People API](https://developers.google.com/people) **MUST** be enabled before use. To do this,

  - Open the Apps Script project.
  - At the left, click Editor code.
  - At the left, next to Services, click Add a service add.
  - Select `Peopleapi` and click Add.

h/t: @AntoineColson - [How to forward email to another address with sendEmail(to,replyTo, subject, body)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43793642/1330560)

h/t: @NightEye - [Google Apps Script Google People API get contacts from contact group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67644672/1330560)

---

```
/*
// for: all incoming e-mail 
//      from a given email address 
//      containing given text in the Subject line
// forward the email to: 
//      members of a "Contacts" label/group
// Values to update:
// - the email address to targetsender (sendersEmail)
// - text contained in the Subject of received emails
// - the id of the target Contact group/labellabel(id)
//
// NOTE: the threads returned by the search may include 
// messages that are outside search date range
//
*/
function fwdEmail(){

  // update the address for the "from" email address
  var sendersEmail = "Google <no-reply@accounts.google.com>"

  // update the text contained in the Subject line
  var queryText = "Security alert"

  // update the ID if the Contact group for the persons
  var labelId = "2e8e7cc882deaaf" // UPDATE for the Contact group ID
  var fwdAddresses = contactsEmail(labelId)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the forwarding addresses are:"+fwdAddresses)

  // get Gmail threads using search query
  var threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread from:"+sendersEmail+" subject:("+queryText+") newer_than:1d");
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Number of threads:"+threads.length) // DEBUG
   
  // loop through threads
  for (var i=0;i<threads.length;i++){
    var thread = threads[i]

    // get messages in each thread
    var msgs = thread.getMessages()
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Thread#:"+i+" number of messages="+msgs.length)

    // loop through thread messages
    for (var m=0;m<msgs.length;m++){
      var message = msgs[m]
      var msgBody = message.getBody()
      var msgDate = message.getDate()
      var msgFrom = message.getFrom()
      var msgUnRead = message.isUnread()
      var msgSubject = message.getSubject()
      var msgAttachment = message.getAttachments()

      // Logger.log("DEBUG: FYI: Message Date: Thread#:"+i+" Message#:"+m+" from: "+msgDate)

      if(msgUnRead === false){
         // Logger.log("DEBUG: Not forwarded: Message is already Read: Thread#:"+i+" Message#:"+m+" from: "+msgFrom+" read status: "+msgUnRead+" date:"+msgDate)
        continue
      }
      if(msgSubject.indexOf(queryText) === -1){
         // Logger.log("DEBUG: Not forwarded: Invalid Subject: Thread#:"+i+" Message#:"+m+" from: "+msgFrom+" read status: "+msgUnRead+" date:"+msgDate+" subject: "+msgSubject)
        continue
      }
      
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: To be forwarded: Thread#:"+i+" Message#:"+m+" from: "+msgFrom+" read status: "+msgUnRead+" subject: "+msgSubject)

      // forward the message
      message.forward(fwdAddresses, {
        subject: "Forwarded: [" + msgSubject + "]", // customizes the subject
        htmlBody: "This is a message that I received<br><br>" //adds your message to the body
          +
          "<div style='text-align: center;'>---------- Forwarded message ----------</div><br>" + msgBody, //centers
        attachments: msgAttachment
      })

      // mark the message as 'read'
      message.markRead(); // mark each forwarded thread as read, one by one

    }
  }
}

/* Query the People API for a specific Group and 
// return the email addreses of the group
// 1 - Update the "labelId" with the your ID of your Group label
// 2 - Make sure that the "Peopleapi" service is enabled BEFORE running this script.
*/
function contactsEmail(labelId) {

  
  var resourceName = "contactGroups/"+labelId
  
  var pGroup = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', {
    personFields: 'emailAddresses,memberships'
  });

  // create a temporary array to hold email addresses
  var eMails = [];

  // get the email addresses
  pGroup.connections.forEach(function (person) {
    person.memberships.forEach(function (membership) {
      if (resourceName == membership.contactGroupMembership.contactGroupResourceName) {
        var addresses = [];
        person.emailAddresses.forEach(function (emailAddress){
          // people can have multiple email addresses, add them all
          addresses.push(emailAddress.value);
        });
        eMails.push(addresses);
      }
    });
  });

  // Logger.log("DEBUG: email addresses are: "+eMails)
  return eMails.join()
  
}
```